# Dynamic JS script load in DOM

Tags: javascript, web, dom

I've been working on a website for my web class (Frl) and we have been asked to do a bank-alike website, and so I went and did that. Now I'm at the point where I have an Account page, in which I have mutliple sections that I need to dynamically load. I've done the most of it, and it works correctly. That's what I thought! Because when I first load the section, the script also loads correctly, but when I remove the section and load it again, the script `(console.log())` says the script has been loaded again, but then, nothing happens. I've tried to remove them from the DOM and reload each time, but it didn't seem to do anything good.

```
export class dynamicLoader {
    constructor(parentElement, template, scripts) {
        this.scriptElements = [];
        this.scripts = scripts;
        this.exportedHTML = template;
        this.template;
        this.parent = parentElement;
        this.appendElement();
    }

    //Template
    getTemplate() {
        let html = this.exportedHTML;
        return html;
    }

    //Handle script load : 
    loadScript(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;
            script.defer = true;
            script.type = 'module';
            script.onload = resolve;
            script.onerror = reject;
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });
    }

    //Append element and load script
    appendElement() {
        this.template = document.createElement('section');
        this.template.innerHTML = this.getTemplate();
        this.parent.appendChild(this.template);

        // Loads scripts
        this.scripts.forEach((element) => {
            this.loadScript(element).then((scriptElement) => {
                console.log('Script: ' + element + ' has been loaded');
                this.scriptElements.push(scriptElement); // Store the script element reference
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(element + ' has not been loaded correctly', error);
            });
        });
    }

    // Remove element and unload scripts
    removeElement() {
        if (this.template) {
            // Remove script elements from the head element
            this.scripts.forEach((element) => {
                const scriptElement = document.querySelector(`script[src="${element}"]`);
                    if (scriptElement) {
                        scriptElement.remove();
                        console.log('Script: ' + element + ' has been removed');
                    }
                });
            // Remove the parent element
            this.parent.removeChild(this.template);
            this.template.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
}
```

This code here, should remove and re-load the script whenever it's being call, but as I said, although it works the first time, it doesn't the second.

Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: If you're not loading a whole new window, there's no reason to reload a script, and in fact it's likely to lead to a host of weird problems.

Comment: So would I just change the script themselve to add an INIT method for their respective code and use that when loading the section ?

Comment: You could do that, or make use of event delegation to reduce the need for re-initialization. (Sometimes re-initialization is necessary, of course.)

Comment: You can't "unload" a script. Once you load the script, the function definitions are in memory. Removing the script element doesn't undo that.

Comment: oh, good you, hence the why and what of it, Okay great, do you have any idea to work around that ?